# How to use mulitple try except in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

this code when given a list of cities goes and searches on google and extract data then covert it into a dataframe

In some cases have to use different xpaths to extract the data. there are three xpaths in total.

Trying to do this :

```
if

   1 doesnt work go to 2 

   2 doesnt work go to 3

   3 doesnt work. 

use driver.quit ()
```

tried this code used NoSuchElementException

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
import pandas as pd
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

df_output = pd.DataFrame(columns=["City", "pincode"])
url = "https://www.google.com/"
chromedriver = ('/home/me/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.get(url)
search = driver.find_element_by_name('q')

mlist1=['polasa']
for i in mlist1:

    try:
        search.send_keys(i,' pincode')
        search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="IAznY"]//div[@class="title"]')))
        elmts = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="IAznY"]//div[@class="title"]')
        df_output = df_output.append(pd.DataFrame(columns=["City", "pincode"], data=[[i,elmts[0].text]])) 
        driver.quit()

    except NoSuchElementException:

        try:
            elements=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='Z0LcW']")
            df_output = df_output.append(pd.DataFrame(columns=["City", "pincode"], data=[[i,elements.text]]))
            driver.quit()

         except NoSuchElementException:

                try:
                    elements=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='Z0LcW AZCkJd']")
                    df_output = df_output.append(pd.DataFrame(columns=["City", "pincode"], data=[[i,elements.text]]))
                    driver.quit()
                except:
                    driver.quit()
```

this code works used one of the 3 tags here

need to combine 3 tags in a single code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import pandas as pd
import os
import html5lib
import json
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
import pandas as pd


url = "https://www.google.com/"
chromedriver = ('/home/me/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.get(url)
search = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
search.send_keys('polasa',' pincode')
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
elements=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='Z0LcW']")
elements.text


``
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need 3 `try-catch`s. You can do this without throwing exceptions by locating elements (plural) given a locator and then check the length of the collection returned. If length = 0, no elements were found.

The locators you are using don't require XPath so you can instead use a CSS selector and combine all three with an OR and avoid the three checks. (Note: you can do the same thing with XPath but the results are messier and harder to read)

Here are your 3 locators combined into one using OR (the comma) in CSS selector syntax

```
div.IAznY div.title, div.Z0LcW, div.Z0LcW.AZCkJd
```

...and the updated code using the combined locator and without the nested `try-catch`.

```
...
locator = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.IAznY div.title, div.Z0LcW, div.Z0LcW.AZCkJd')

for i in mlist1:
    search.send_keys(i,' pincode')
    search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located(*locator)
    elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(*locator)
    df_output = df_output.append(pd.DataFrame(columns=["City", "pincode"], data=[[i,elements[0].text]]))

driver.quit()
```

NOTE: I used your original locators and wasn't returning any results with any of the three. Are you sure they are correct?

Also note... I pulled the `driver.quit()` out of the loop. I'm not sure if you intended it to be inside or not but from the code provided, if the `try` succeeds in the first iteration, the browser will quit. You only have one item so you probably didn't notice this yet but would have been confused when you added another item to the iteration.

Comment: `TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-d443e7126369> in <module>()
     14     search.send_keys(i,' pincode')
     15     search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
---> 16     WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located(*locator))
     17     elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(*locator)
     18     df_output = df_output.append(pd.DataFrame(columns=["City", "pincode"], data=[[i,elements.text]]))

TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)`

Comment: in your code the locators are fetching no data and i used `driver.quit()` for the loop only. I need the code to run iit loop for different usecases

Comment: this code works fine . Check this code works and fetches the data

Comment: `url = "https://www.google.com/"
chromedriver = ('/home/me/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.get(url)
search = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
search.send_keys('polasa',' pincode')
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
elements=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='Z0LcW']")`

Comment: There was one thing I meant to ask and forgot... does `data=[[i,elements.text]]` work? `elements` is a collection. In your first `try` it uses `elmts[0].text`... should the other two be `elements[0].text`?

Comment: I updated the answer to use just the first returned element. That should be a parallel of what you just posted.

Comment: ```---> 11     WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located(*locator))
     12     elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(*locator)
     13     df_output = df_output.append(pd.DataFrame(columns=["City", "pincode"], data=[[i,elements[0].text]]))

TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given) ```